# ADL in case of equal-named member function

Tags: c++, interface, argument-dependent-lookup, non-member-functions

The situation is that some member function `bar::Bar::frobnicate` wants to utilize ADL to find a function from some unknown namespace, within a function that has an identical name. However, it only finds its own name.

### Testcase

(*Note* that in reality, `Bar` is a `Foo`-agnostic template; this is just the reproducible, minimal testcase)

```
namespace foo {
    struct Foo {};
    void frobnicate(Foo const &) {}
}

namespace bar {
    struct Bar {
        void frobnicate() {
            foo::Foo foo;
            frobnicate(foo); // <-- error
        }
    };
}

int main () {
    bar::Bar x;
    x.frobnicate();
    frobnicate(foo::Foo());
}
```

Results in:

```
test.cc: In member function ‘void bar::Bar::frobnicate()’:
test.cc:10:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘bar::Bar::frobnicate(foo::Foo&)’
test.cc:10:31: note: candidate is:
test.cc:8:18: note: void bar::Bar::frobnicate()
test.cc:8:18: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

### Standard

I understand that this is correct compiler behaviour:

> #### 3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup *[basic.lookup.unqual]*
>
> (...) name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name (...)

and only *after* unqualified lookup failed, argument dependent lookup comes into play:

> #### 3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup *[basic.lookup.argdep]*
>
> When the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an unqualified-id, other namespaces not considered
>   during the usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched

### Workaround

My current workaround is to introduce a special traits class that does not define the clashing name itself:

```
    struct BarTraits {
        void frobnicate_(foo::Foo const &b) {
            frobnicate(b);
        }
    };
```

or this ligher version:

```
    void frobnicate_(foo::Foo const &c) { frobnicate(c); }
```

### Question

Are there better alternatives than introducing such traits classes?

Explicitly qualifying the call as `foo::frobnicate(foo)` is not an option here, because (as mentioned) the `Bar` class is a template upon `Foo` in reality and should not only work for types in the `foo` namespace.

Comment: +1 for making me lookup ADL, I learnt something new today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out yourself, adding a member function `frobnicate` to the class interface of `Bar` (or `Bar<T>` in the template case), will prevent ADL from finding `foo::frobnicate`.

The easiest -[**and in this case idiomatic**](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)- way to add `frobnicate` functionality to a class `Bar` (or to a class template `Bar<T>`) is to add a non-member function `frobnicate(Bar)`  (or function template `frobnicate(Bar<T>)`) to the namespace `bar`

```
namespace foo {
    struct Foo {};
    void frobnicate(Foo const &)  {}
}

namespace bar {
    template<class T>
    struct Bar {    
       T t;    
    }; 

    template<class T>
    void frobnicate(Bar<T> const& b)
    {
        frobnicate(b.t);    
    }
}

int main () {
    bar::Bar<foo::Foo> x;
    frobnicate(x);
    frobnicate(foo::Foo());
}
```

If you insist on having a member function, you will have to rename it to something like `do_frobnicate()`. I would not use type traits tricks to get the same behavior as it is an indirect approach, and makes the class interfaces much harder to understand (remember Stroustrup's motto: "represent your ideas directly in code").

Comment: The thing with the member function is that I wanted my `Bar` to also satisfy some abstract interface (it's declaration looks like `template<typename T, typename Base> class Bar`, and it is basically a container of `T`). I think it would indeed be cleanest to not implement that abstract interface and have a free function, and then reuse `Bar` as a member in something that implements `Base`, but I have to think about it a bit more. +1 so far.

Comment: @phresnel It is indeed important to consider that type of interface `Bar` is supposed to have. It is also important to consider whether `foo` and `bar` are related enough to be merged. See e.g. this old Sutter column [What's in a class](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm).

Comment: To give more insight: The real situation is a Ray Tracer. I have shapes and primitives, where a shape is just a shape, and a primitive is a bit like a shape, but adds materials. The `Bar` in fact is a "Bounding Interval Hierarchy" (a tree structure). To avoid code duplication, the BIH is generic enough to be able to be a shape, or a primitive, or even something else. That is, `foo` and `bar` are unfortunately not related anough, `foo` can actually be a Sphere, a Triangle, or even another, nested BIH.  I think, currently the cleanest way is to provide a sort of container adapters, which ...

Comment: ... implement a Shape interface and a Primitve interface for my generic BIH, so I would not be using the BIH directly, and just accept that my BIH-implementation is just a toolbox to implement real containers on it.

Comment: @phresnel adding "outside" `frobnicate` functionality to such a complicated class hierarchy really is best done through non-member functions, in order not further increase the classes responsibility. It's also the way the Standard Library works: containers that provide a concise storage interface, and a whole bunch of algorithms that operate on such classes through iterators.

Comment: @TemplateRex: +1 for the nice answer; however, I've a doubt. If I'm, like the OP, creating `Foo` on the fly and have no requirement to store a `Foo` as `Bar`'s member, I can do away with the template right? I tried it by creating `Foo` inside `bar::frobnicate` and it seems to work without the template.

Comment: @legends2k sure, if you only ever use temporary `foo::Foo` objects, there is no need to have an extra `frobnicate` in namespace `bar`. The answer shows how to call it on `Foo` objects inside another class.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Aah, I see your point. The only downside here would be that the class' data member should be public for the non-member function to access it, but I see that having it as a member function will make ADL not work, so this should be a happy medium which became an idiom.

Comment: @legends2k the public data member was just for illustration purposes. in production code, it could be hidden behind a getter()

Comment: @TemplateRex: True, the usual way of exposing data through an interface instead of the actual member

Comment: In the case of a class, a `friend` statement may become necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this trick

```
namespace dummy { void your_func(may be some parameteres); }
struct bar { 
   void member() {
      using dummy::your_func; // now your call will find that and ADL will kick in
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do it with a proxy function

```
namespace utils 
{
int lookup_adl(int arg) 
{
  return lookup(arg);// ADL search
}
struct Foo 
{
  int lookup(int arg) { return ::utils::lookup_adl(arg);}
};
}
```